# TreeView without duplicate all data to model

Tags: treeview, gtkmm

I have a huge amount of data, already stored in STL containers. It feels very bad to do full copy for all data to `Gtk::ListStore`. And also, my data structure contains big gaps in some rows, which simply can be filled with a default value if the line of the view becomes visible. To store tons of default values into a model is also a bad overhead.

For this I thought it is easy to setup a own model which will then provide some entry points/callbacks where I simply can provide my own data from my containers.

But I can not find any line of documentation.

Here a standard TreeView, but no idea how to improve with own model:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-treeview-examples.html.en

In https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-treeview-model.html.en I found the beautiful sentence

```
Although you can theoretically implement your own Model,
you will normally use either the ListStore or TreeStore model classes.
```

After that I take a look into the sources... well, because Gtkmm is only a wrapper over the C-code, it is not simply deriving from a class and overwrite some methods. It is more to pick up the underlaying c code if my interpretation of the code I saw is correct.

Anyway, is there any chance to get some lines of code where the ListStore is replaced by a own model?